# What's the difference between these two approaches to namespacing?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, namespaces

I've got the first file in my code directory as follows

**myNamespace.js**

```
var myNamespace = {};
```

Then my subsequent files can look as one of the two following ways.

**first**

```
(function (ns) {
    ns.DoStuff = function(){
        // do stuff
    }
})(myNamespace);
```

**second**

```
myNamespace.DoStuff = function(){
    //do stuff
}
```

So what is the difference between these two methods? Both seem to work for me. Is there a more generally accepted convention?

<sup>sorry, still new to javascript</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your first one, you've used `this` where I'm pretty sure you meant `ns`:

```
ns.DoStuff = function() {
};
```

Leaving that aside, your first approach tends to be better because you've created a nice little scoping function for yourself, which allows you to have private data and functions available to all of the public methods you create on your namespace, without making them globals. E.g.:

```
(function(ns) {
    function privateFunction() {
    }

    ns.DoStuff = function() {
        privateFunction();   // <=== works fine
    };

})(myNamespace);]
privateFunction(); // <=== doesn't work, because it's private
```

I like doing it that way partially because [I have thing against anonymous functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), and so I wouldn't define `DoStuff` as above, but rather like this:

```
(function(ns) {
    ns.DoStuff = Namespace$DoStuff;
    function Namespace$DoStuff() {
    }
})(myNamespace);
```

Now the function I've assigned to `myNamespace.DoStuff` has a proper name, which helps me out when I'm debugging my code. But that name doesn't pollute the global namespace, which helps me stay sane and avoid conflicts with other code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've edited my question based on the `this` mistake.

Comment: uh oh... your edit complicated things a bit for me :( - do you actually mean `myNamespace$DoStuff`? And what does the `$` symbol represent in that name?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: The name can be whatever you want --`myNamespace$DoStuff`, `myNamespace_DoStuff`, `fred`, whatever. Whatever you want to see on call stacks in the debugger. :-) The `$` is not significant, it's just a valid character for identifiers. In my own work, I use initially-capped "namespaces" (usually; e.g. `Nifty`), and use the convention `<constructor>$<functionName>` for functions that become properties of instances created by constructor functions, and use `<namespace>_<functionName>` for functions that will be on the namespace directly. (And I applied the wrong one above!)

Answer (score 3):

Your **first** approach will not work. It would create `DoStuff` on the `global object` (most likely `window`). You would need to replace `this` with `ns`, after you did that, there is no difference between the two approaches.

The former will have the adventage that you might be able to closure all your application/file related stuff into that outer self-invoking closure function. So you won't clobber the global namespace.

```
(function (ns) {
    var foo = 10,
        bar = 42;

    ns.DoStuff = function(){
        console.log('foo is ', foo, ' and its not available globally');
    }
})(myNamespace);
```

Comment: How can I make a variable available globally while still using this method?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: actually you don't want to do that. Writting stuff into the global object is one of the most bad/dangerous things in Javascript. However, you can always access `window.XXX = 42;` directly from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a more detailed question separate from this one. I've got my answer here.