# How to update internal config from outside the namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, private-methods

I've got a javascript file as follows

```
(function (rpc) {

    rpc.loadHomeBanner = rpc_loadHomeBanner;
    function rpc_loadHomeBanner(){

        // AN is used by Sencha Animator as an Animation variable
        rpc.AN ={};

        rpc.AN.Controller = {

            setConfig: function(configData) {
                // update config crap
            }
        };

        var configData = {
           // config crap
        };

        rpc.AN.Controller.setConfig(configData);
    }
})(rpc);
```

Now on the very first load of the page, I call

```
rpc.loadHomeBanner();
```

and it fires up just as I need it to.

The problem is that I have a `handleOrientationChange` method that needs to update the config from outside the namespace (I don't want to fire the loadHomeBanner method because of overhead).

```
 handleOrientationChange: function(){
        // Updating the config for the animation to ensure appropriate width.
        var configData = {
            // config crap
        };
        rpc.AN.Controller.setConfig(configData);
    }
```

How can I call `rpc.AN.controller.setConfig` from outside the scope of the closure?

Comment: You are passing `rpc` from the outside, so you should be able to just call `rpc.AN.controller.setConfig` from anywhere where `rpc` is visible. I don't see any advantage of the closure here actually.

Comment: @FelixKling: I would hope this is not all the code in that module, Chase is showing just what's necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already be accessible considering you've passed the `rpc` object into that code module.

Comment: hrm... I feel a little stupid. The error I was getting was being thrown inside the `setConfig` method. I should do a little more troubleshooting before asking stupid questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `factory`.

```
var createRPC = function( rpc ) {
    rpc.AN = {
        Controller: {
            setConfig: function( configData ) {
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        updateConfig: function( configData ) {
            rpc.AN.Controller.setConfig( configData );
        };
    };
};
```

and then use it like

```
var rpc = createRPC({});

//handle orientation change
rpc.updateConfig({
    some: 'data'
});
```

Comment: note his other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264349/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-approaches-to-namespacing/9264443#9264443 for the object form he is usings context.